# Concatenating Sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns pest1,pest2,pest3......pest12. Query below calculates sum of each column

```
SELECT SUM(pestpopulation1)as pestpopulation1,SUM(pestpopulation2)as pestpopulation2,
  SUM(pestpopulation3)as pestpopulation3,SUM(pestpopulation4)as pestpopulation4,
  SUM(pestpopulation5)as pestpopulation5,SUM(pestpopulation6)as pestpopulation6,
  SUM(pestpopulation7)as pestpopulation7,SUM(pestpopulation8)as pestpopulation8,
  SUM(pestpopulation9)as pestpopulation9,SUM(pestpopulation10)as pestpopulation10,
  SUM(pestpopulation11)as pestpopulation11,SUM(pestpopulation12)as pestpopulation12 
FROM transformed_table.
```

I have made checkboxes for each column in c#. What i want is what ever the user selects the option the query should run accordingly.

for e.g user checks pest1 and pest2 query should look like

```
SELECT SUM(pestpopulation1)as pestpopulation1,SUM(pestpopulation2)as pestpopulation2
FROM transformed_table.
```

is there any way to concatenate a query because if i write the queries for all the possible options it will cost a lot of time.

Comment: You could use Dynamic SQL. Basically you write the query based on what pestpopulation item was selected. Let me know if you need help with it.

Comment: well i am really new to this plz help..just give me 1 example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

```
string sql = "SELECT ";
if (checkBox1.Checked) sql += "SUM(pestpopulation1) as pestpopulation1, ";
if (checkBox2.Checked) sql += "SUM(pestpopulation2) as pestpopulation2, ";
// etc.
sql += "'' as dummy";  // Either this or remove the last comma.
sql += " FROM transformed_table;";
```

Something like this will do

But seriously, you should try a little and then show what you have tried just to show that you did something.

Comment: it would however still preferred to use SPROCS for performance and security as well as maintainability reasons. no matter which angle you look at it from, C# or SQL - you STILL need to do the same query

Comment: im surprised you don't know how :) plenty of examples with a bit of research on google. whatever you have written in your example should be transferred to a SPROC instead. SPROC is T-SQL compiled